# How can I delete the Kubernetes dashboard from kube-system?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

I can not remove kubernetes-dashboard from Minikube. I tried deleting the deployment "deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard" multiple times. But it gets recreated automatically in a few seconds.

I am using the following command to delete the deployment:

> kubectl delete deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system

I even tried to edit the deployment by setting the replica count to zero. But even it gets reset automatically after a few seconds.

The same thing happens for nginx-ingress deployment in kube-system.

Comment: Please do share the yaml or something that you gave to start the deployment

Comment: I enabled the dashboard by "minikube dashboard --url".

Didn't use any external yaml file.

Comment: It is a possibility that the dashboard is static deployment in minikube, and it's file should be present in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`. If it is present there, by removing that file it will automatically delete it. I am not sure that it is static deployment in minikube or not. Please check

Comment: @PrafullLadha 
Actually, It's not present in the menifests directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to disable the dashboard addon using minikube first. Then deleting the deployment did work for me.

```
minikube addons disable dashboard
```

And in case of ingress:

```
minikube addons disable ingress
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below command:

```
kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-rc5/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please do try the following:

```
kubectl get secret,sa,role,rolebinding,services,deployments --namespace=kube-system | grep dashboard
```

Comment: Tried already. It displays secret, service, and deployment. I deleted all of these. It didn't work.